# Is it needed to build containers first before use docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker compose solution is created to up all dependent container at once, I read some articles explained how to rise multiple containers altogether at once:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:9.6.6
    ports:
      - 9932:5432
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  myapp:
    image: myapp
    links:
      - postgresql
    depends_on:
      - "postgresql"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000
```

1) So do I need to build / run manually `myapp` and `postgresql` with `docker build` and `docker run` commands? (in case of postgresql possible can `docker run` - it pulls it from docker hub) and only after can use `docker-compose up`

2) If I add:

```
app:
    build: ./app
```

will it avoid me from 1)? (can use `docker-compose up` without `docker build` and `docker run` preparation steps)

Comment: What have you tried and what errors did you encounter? Be sure to include the commands you have run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the `docker-compose up` and:

- If you provide the tag `image` and no tag `build` like your `postgresql` service in this case, the system will first look for the image name in your local machine (`postgres:9.6.6` in this case). If it cannot find, it will try to pull from the Internet (default at Dockerhub)
- If you provide the tag `build`, it will try to [build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) your app image first based on the provided `context` and `Dockerfile` location and spin up a container based on that.
- If you provide both `build` and `image` tag, it will build and save the image as the image name that you defined.

So to answer your questions:

1. You can just use `docker-compose up` without first running `docker run` or `docker pull`. However, for a private registry, you will first need to login so that Docker will have permission to pull from.
2. Yes as explained above.